# Apply generic visitor to generic derived class of non-generic base class

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, visitor-pattern

Currently I have something like this:

```
public abstract class Base {...}
public class Derived<T> : Base {...}

class Visitor {
    public static void Visit<T>(Derived<T> d) {
        ...
    }
}
```

My question is, given a `Base` reference that I know is a `Derived` instance, how can I apply that `Visit` function to that object, using the correct generic instantiation? I understand that the answer will probably involve a type-checked dynamic downcast, to make sure that the object isn't some other type derived from base, which is all fine. I assume the answer involves reflection, which is also fine, though I'd prefer if there was a way to do it without reflection.

It's also ok if the answer involves an abstract method on `Base` and `Derived`; I do have enough control of the classes to add that. But at the end of the day, I need to call a generic function, correctly instantiated with the `T` of the Derived type.

Sorry if this is an easy question; I come from a C++ background, where my instinct would be to use a CRTP or something else like that, which isn't possible in C#.

**EDIT:**

Here's an example of what I need to be able to do:

```
Base GetSomeDerivedInstance() { ...; return new Derived<...>(); }
var b = GetSomeDerivedInstance();

// This is the line that needs to work, though it doesn't necessarily
// need to have this exact call signature. The only requirement is that
// the instantiated generic is invoked correctly.
Visitor.Visit(b);
```

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean but i think you're looking for generic constraints https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx

Comment: Your code should work as-is. `public class Foo : Base { }; Visitor.Visit<Foo>(new Derived<Foo>());` compiles just fine.

Comment: Jacob: not exactly. I'm trying to do something more like: `Base b = createDerived(); Visitor.Visit(b);`

Comment: You should probably update your question to show what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Jacob Post edit'd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, answers involving double-dispatch and More Classes are going to be superior than using reflection to do what inheritance should do for you.

Normally this means defining an 'accept' method on the visitable class, which simply calls the correct Visit method from the visitor.

```
class Base
{
    public virtual void Accept(Visitor visitor)
    {
        visitor.Visit(this); // This calls the Base overload.
    }
}

class Derived<T> : Base
{
    public override void Accept(Visitor visitor)
    {
        visitor.Visit(this); // this calls the Derived<T> overload.
    }
}

public class Visitor
{
    public void Visit(Base @base)
    {
        ...
    }

    public void Visit<T>(Derived<T> derived)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Then you can do what you mentioned in your question, with a small modification:

```
Base b = createDerived();
b.Accept(new Visitor());
```

If your visit method is a static class that you can't change for whatever reason, you could always wrap this into a dummy instance visitor class which calls the right static method.

Comment: What's the @base syntax? I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: My only concern about this solution is the circular dependency between Visitor, Base, and Derived, introduced by Base.Accept. Is this worth worrying about, or a non-issue?

Comment: @Lucretiel, the @ syntax is used to disambiguate an identifier from a keyword-- it's needed there because 'base' is a keyword.

Comment: I don't think that the circular dependency is worth worrying about as such, but the deep knowledge that the visitor has of the entire inheritance tree is a common criticism.

In my opinion, the added maintenance cost when adding more things to the inheritance hierarchy (the fact that you need to modify your visitor class rather than extend with something new) is better than the reflection-based alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

(Edited for clarity)

The following will use a variable called "anyvalue" whose type is only known at run-time. Then we'll create an instance of your Derived class based on the type of anyvalue. Once we have that instance, we can use reflection to get the correct Visit method.

```
var anyvalue = 5; // This value could have come from anywhere. 
...    
var derivedType = typeof (Derived<>).MakeGenericType(anyvalue.GetType());
var dvalue = Activator.CreateInstance(derivedType);
var method = typeof(Visitor).GetMethod("Visit");
var genericMethod = method.MakeGenericMethod(new[] { anyvalue.GetType() });
genericMethod.Invoke(null, new [] { dvalue });
```

What is a little confusing is that this is a skeletal example and you do not use the original value for anything other than getting a run-time type. In the real world implementation, I would assume a constructor would use that value to set internal state in the Derived instance. That is not covered here because that is not part of the question that was asked.

**UPDATE:**

I think this will do what you want.  Note that I created the itemarray so that we would have some run-time values. They have to be created somewhere. So whether they are passed in as object[] or provided some other way, they had to be constructed with a type specifier somewhere. Also, this assumes that  Derived<> is the only derived class. Otherwise, this is not safe code.

```
var itemarray = new Base[] { new Derived<int>(), new Derived<string>() };

foreach (var baseObject in itemarray)
{
    var derivedType = baseObject.GetType();
    var visitMethod = typeof(Visitor)
        .GetMethod("Visit")
        .MakeGenericMethod(derivedType.GetGenericArguments());
    visitMethod.Invoke(null, new[] { baseObject });
}
```

The Accept approach does seem a bit more manageable. My goal was to answer the question you asked without passing judgment on your approach. I have needed to use this approach several times. I wrote an entity framework about 9 years ago. I had a really hard time doing exactly what you are trying to do. I created base classes that were not generic so that I could share basic functionality regardless of the generic type. It proved challenging. I am not sure I would do it the same way now. I'd probably investigate a few patterns just as you are doing.

Comment: The problem with the reflection solution you've proposed is that I don't know, even at call time, the exact type that the `Derived` was instantiated with.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. In this example, you do not have to know the type at compile-time. Note that the type used with MakeGenericType is Derived<> with no type specifier. The type of the variable used in the parameter is being extracted at run-time. There are no compile-time requirements here other than knowing you want some flavor of Derived.

Comment: What about all the use of `anyvalue.GetType()`? That implies that I know `T` is `int` (or some fixed type) at the time I invoke this solution.

Comment: I am not sure what gives you that impression. There is no explicit mention of an int. The GetType() method is how you get the type at run-time. It is going to use whatever that value happens to be when it is encountered at run-time. That is the whole point of the MakeGenericxxxx calls. You do NOT know that anyvalue is an int. Imagine that anyvalue is a parameter that was passed from somewhere else and you don't know the type at all. That is where GetType() comes in.

Comment: The problem is that I don't even know what object I'm encountering at runtime. All I have is this: "Base myBase; Visitor.Visit(b)." I know that `myBase` is a Derived type, but I don't have any object I can call GetType on.

Comment: Why was my answer downvoted? I know there are other good answers. But I feel like mine directly answered the OP's question unless I am missing something really obvious.

Comment: I removed the downvote because the original answer didn't solve my original problem; I've readded it because your current update does appear to be correct. As it happens, I'm in basically the same boat as you are, and I ended up redoing my original solution with much more functionality in the base class, and more use of virtuals, than trying to do everything statically.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like the following:

```
Base foo = new Derived<int>();

var method = typeof(Visitor).GetMethod("Visit", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
method.MakeGenericMethod(foo.GetType().GenericTypeArguments.First()).Invoke(null, new[] {foo});
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're meaning something like this?

```
public class Derived<T>
{
}

public abstract class Derivable<T>
{
    public Derived<T> CreateDerived()
    {
        return new Derived<T>();
    }
}

public class Foo : Derivable<Foo>
{
}

class Visitor
{
    public static void Visit<T>(Derived<T> obj)
    {
        Console.Out.WriteLine("Called!");
    }
}

void Main()
{
    var obj = new Foo();
    var derived = obj.CreateDerived();
    Visitor.Visit(derived);
}
```

If the creation of the `Derived<T>` is `T`-specific, then you'd make the `CreateDerived` method abstract and implement it for each `T`. Or use an `IDerivable<T>` *interface* instead if you don't want it as your base class.